# Check and relaunch an application if its not running

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a batch file together to put in the all users startup folder.

I want it to check every 5 seconds to see if *`wswc.exe`* is running, if it is **do nothing**, if it is not then start:

```
 c:\program files\vmware\vmware view\client\bin\wswc.exe
```

Any help would greatly be appricated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
:LOOP
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq wswc.exe" | find /i "wswc.exe" >nul && echo It's running || start "" "c:\program files\vmware\vmware view\client\bin\wswc.exe"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work. it is a constant loop, but doesnt launch, or relaunch the application.

Comment: Sorry, your right, I have edited it now which seems to be working. The `start` had a quoted path as the filename which it interprets as the title, so a blank title fixes that. For some reason it didn't like `rem` in the command to run if it was already running, so I have just replaced with `echo`.